# Change artifact Storage on Apache archiva repository

Tags: amazon-s3, dreamhost, archiva

I have installed an local copy of archiva in my local machine. When i upload artifact or "mvn deploy" artifact to store artifacts - it uses my local system to store files. I want to store artifacts with my dreamObjects cloud account with amazon s3 filesystem. And when ever needed the artifact should download from there. I need some Idea how i can implement that. I already have tested filesystem using s3 into dreamobject. Need the clue where i should work on archiva.